# Nginx rewrites parent rules with same key in sub-files?

Tags: linux, nginx, devops, nginx-config

Accessing the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file I have the following rule:

```
server {}
http {

    access_log   logs/access.log  main;
    error_log    logs/error.log  error;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

In another file, called `etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf`, I have the code:

```
http {
    blablabla …
```

When **NGINX** loads the settings, will the **HTTP** code block that was inside `NGINX.CONF` be “merged” with the settings included below or will it simply be replaced?

In this scenario for example, will the **LOGS** continue to be saved in the folder even if `CUSTOM.CONF` doesn't implement anything about it?

**My current issue:**
I can't see the logs that should be printed in the `error/access.log` files, remembering that my application is generating a **500 HTTP error**.

Comment: You are definitely doing something wrong. Those `*.conf` files in the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` directory usually contains per-domain server configuration and should start with `server { ...` rather that `http { ...`. nginx won't start with your config at all. To check nginx config for errors use `nginx -t` command from console.

Comment: @IvanShatsky, you might even be correct, but, according to the feedback from nginx, everything is running perfectly, no syntax errors.
`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`
`nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you can have more then a single `http block` you should not do it. But having an `http` block in another `http` block IS NOT ALLOWED and will raise an error on startup. Just tested this on my instance. So you should check the output of `nginx -T` and check the configuration.

The NGINX configuration works in an hierarchical order. Means a directive you set in the `http` context can be overwritten in the `server` or `location` context if supported.